# GeneralException on multiple edits in a promise chain

Tags: excel, promise, office-js

In my Excel add-in I want to perform multiple edits on my document sequentially.
I'm using the promise chain to achive this.

Unfortunately I'm getting a `GeneralException: An internal error has occurred.` from some of my edits.

The following example performs 250 edits and I get something between 20 and 30 GeneralExceptions in each run. (with Office 2016, in Office online it's much worse)

**Example:**

```js
var promise;

Office.initialize = function (reason) {

  // add awesome addin initialize code here

  promise = new OfficeExtension.Promise(function (resolve, reject) { resolve(null); });

  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    insertData("Data" + i);
  }
}

function insertData(data) {
  if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", "1.0")) {
    //insert the data into the spreadsheet
    promise = promise.then(function () {
      Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        var range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        range.getCell(0, 0).values = data;
        range.getCell(1, 0).select();
        return ctx.sync()
      }).catch(function (error) {
        addLogEntry(error.message);
      });
    });
  }
  else if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("WordApi", "1.0")) {
    promise = promise.then(function () {
      Word.run(function (ctx) {
        var body = ctx.document.body;

        var selectedRange = ctx.document.getSelection();
        selectedRange.insertText(data + "\n", 'End');
        selectedRange.select('End');

        return ctx.sync();
      }).catch(function (error) {
        addLogEntry(error.message);
      });
    });
  }
}

function addLogEntry(message) {
  // log message here
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here the stack trace of the error:

```
"GeneralException: An internal error has occurred.
   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.debug.js:9329:6)
   at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.debug.js:11207:8)
   at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.debug.js:11217:8)
   at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.debug.js:11193:9)
   at lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.debug.js:11027:8)"
```

Comment: First, try switching to the debug version of Office.js so that the stacktrace has meaningful function names.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know that this exists. Stack trace updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but it is not very elegant and VERY slow (especially in office online)

maybe someone can come up with something better? ;)

Here the fixed `insertData` function:

```
var isSending = false;

function insertData(data) {
  if (!isSending) {
    isSending = true;
    if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", "1.0")) {
      //insert the data into the spreadsheet
      //promise = promise.then(function () {
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {
          var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
          var range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();

          range.getCell(0, 0).values = data;
          range.getCell(1, 0).select();

          return ctx.sync()
        }).then(function () {
          isSending = false;
          if (queue.length > 0) {
            insertData(queue.splice(0, 1)[0]);
          }
        }).catch(function (error) {
          addLogEntry(error.message);
        });
      //});
    }
    else if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("WordApi", "1.0")) {
      //promise = promise.then(function () {
        Word.run(function (ctx) {
          var body = ctx.document.body;
          var selectedRange = ctx.document.getSelection();

          selectedRange.insertText(data + "\n", 'End');
          selectedRange.select('End');

          return ctx.sync();
        }).then(function () {
          isSending = false;
          if (queue.length > 0) {
            insertData(queue[0]);
            queue = queue.splice(0, 1);
          }
        }).catch(function (error) {
          addLogEntry(error.message);
        });
      //});
    }
  }
  else {
    queue.push(data);
  }
}
```